# Redirect to anther website with autentication in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Scenario :

• I have an website (AAA.Com) that I need to type user and password to access it

• After validated, I rediret to another website (ZZZ.com)

question:

How can I prevent access to the ZZZ.com site without validation made in AAA.com?

p.s. I work with Asp.net, MVC and Bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when any user access the aaa.com create the cookie name  with some name , then after validating pass the  cookie created to zzz.com.
if any user user access zzz.com , here you can check the cookie name availability or not.
In this way you can manage this.

Comment: Good idea.. Thank you